# On load pull matching/tuning of the output of a power amplifier, the insertion of a filter and an isolator or circulator

Tags: rf

Suppose I have a power amplifier already output matched for maximum power and ready to be connected to an antenna.
Now suppose I decided to insert a notch filter at the PA output to suppress a signal, that would make the amplifier see a different impedance, thus possibly changing its performance.
Can I remedy for that by inserting an isolator or a circulator  between the PA output and the filter?

Comment: The circulator could change the load the PA sees, just like the filter does.

Comment: Why not put the filter at the input to the spec an?

Comment: If the isolator has an input impedance of 50 ohm (just like the antenna) why would that change the load?

Comment: Why not use an elliptic (or Cauer) filter (similar to a pi filter but one extra component) to maintain impedance at the wanted frequency and provide a block at the unwanted frequency? Numbers matter so, if you can, release the two frequencies for passing and blocking.

Comment: @Andy Aka, the blocking frequency range is 2401 to 2423 MHz, while the passing frequency range is 2310 to 2390 MHz,  I still want to know why wouldn't an isolator protect the amplifier from any disturbance the filter may cause?

Comment: You'd need to show a schematic.

Comment: Don't know how to do that!